# no consigo abrir una pagina html que esta en un servidor apache en una maquina en otra maquina virtual

Tags: html, apache

Tengo que abrir el documento `index.html` que tengo en *htdocs* de *Apache* en mi máquina de Windows 2008 en una máquina virtual de 2007, pero me pone que no encuentra dicha pagina web, he intentado algunos consejos online pero aún así no lo consigo como por ejemplo :

- Abres el archivo `http.conf` en la carpeta *conf* de tu directorio apache.

Lo editas y buscas la entrada `Controls who can get stuff from this server.`

Verás debajo que tienes esto:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Pues tienes que permitirle el acceso desde cualquier sitio, para lo cual con comentar la línea de `Deny from all` te bastará.

```
Order Deny, Allow
# Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Suena a que quieres `Allow from all`

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que indicas ahí, el codigo esta diciendole a Apache que al sitio web solo pueden acceder navegadores de la misma maquina.

Para hacer el sitio accesible debes colocar:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

O tambien:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```